# How to validate Entity Framework CodeFirst mappings against existing database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When `DbContext` is instantiated it validates conceptual model only.
But when first query is executed context performs validation against Db.

**Is it possible to check all the mappings against database without issuing queries?** 
I'd like something like `context.ValidateAgainstDb(connection)`

Now we do such integration testing in the following way:

We use AutoFixture to generate 'trash' entities. After that we switch constraints off and add these entities via `DbSet` calling `SaveChanges()`.

In principle, this process can be to completely automated.
But before reinventing the wheel I'd like to know whether ready solution of the problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any()

EDIT
If you are looking for a check without any migration, I think there is not. Thinking about how EF migration works (__MigrationHistory contains the POCO model) I think that EF does not have a way to know if the DBMS model is ok for the POCO model.